# how to get out of booting to safemode without fully booting?

Tags: windows-10, safe-mode

Context: I was trying to fix a computer that was crashing on login, I made it default to booting in safemode to see if it would log in there (it didn't), I got the files off the computer by installing Linux on another partition on the computer (Well, actually, on an external drive, because I was a little nervous about messing with Windows' default partitions), and then, after extracting the files, I made a mistake:

I ran a factory reset. I assumed that booting to safemode was a thing that was true of that windows installation, and not something larger than it. I was, as the computer has informed me more than once now, wrong.

Now, the computer is failing to boot whenever I try to boot the windows environment, pointing out that it can't very well install Windows in safemode.

Does anyone know how I can get this computer's windows (installer) installation of safemode? The linux installation is still fully operational, if that helps. The Windows installation doesn't boot - since it's only an installer that can't boot in safe mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only suggestion I could give would be to try editing the boot options in boot.ini or using bcdedit.  You *might* be able to access the boot.ini file using the linux boot, or you can used bcdedit if you have a windows rescue disc.  You can make a windows rescue disc from a working windows machine, preferably the same version of windows that's on the machine that you're working on.  Though, I've never encountered the situation you're describing so I'm not positive you'll be able to fix the problem by changing boot settings/parameters.

Here's a [guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/editing-boot-options) on MS website for editing boot options and [another for bcdedit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcdedit-command-line-options).

The boot option for safe mode is "safeboot".  You may have to locate and remove that from the default boot option.

Comment: Ultimately the rescue disc (I assume that's the repair/install drive?) was the correct strategy. (Doing that editing manually from Linux would probably have been possible, but I decided to leave that as a last resort)

I had to change the boot order so the USB would boot first, but luckily my Linux installation gave me access to (among other things) the boot order from the opening screen, which gave me access to the USB, which gave me access to the command prompt. I might have been able to just install from the USB, but I assumed that would require a license, and one came with the computer.